# Why does this return NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

```
model.qty = (parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val()) == NaN) ? 
  0 : 
  parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val());

// model.qty === NaN when #amendOrderQty is left blank
```

I am trying to set a value of 0 when the field is left blank. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "isFinite" instead.

```
var x = parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val();
model.qty = isFinite(x) ? x : 0;
```

Comment: Probably a good idea considering the MDN marks `isNaN()` as broken (for non-numeric strings) :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the comparison operator with `NaN`, it will **always** return `false`.

Use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead

```
var qty = parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val());
model.qty = isNaN(qty) ? 0 : qty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly compare something to `NaN` because

```
NaN === NaN
```

always returns false.

In light of this, you should replace

```
parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val()) == NaN
```

with

```
isNan(parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val()))
```

Your code, refactored and fixed, should look something like this:

```
var orderQtyVal = parseInt($('#amendOrderQty').val());
model.qty = isNaN(orderQtyVal) ? 0 : orderQtyVal;
```